# Merge sort in Scheme

Tags: sorting, scheme, mergesort

```
(define (merge-sort lst (lt? <))
  (define (truthy=? a b)
    (eq? (not a) (not b)))

  (let sort ((lst lst)
             (size (length lst))
             (flip #f))
    (define (merge l r (res '()))
      (cond ((null? l) (append-reverse r res))
            ((null? r) (append-reverse l res))
            ((truthy=? (lt? (car r) (car l)) flip)
             (merge l (cdr r) (cons (car r) res)))
            (else
             (merge (cdr l) r (cons (car l) res)))))

    (if (<= size 1) lst
        (let*-values (((mid) (quotient size 2))
                      ((l r) (split-at lst mid)))
          (merge (sort l mid (not flip))
                 (sort r (- size mid) (not flip)))))))
```

Tested with Racket and Guile; requires SRFIs [1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) and [11](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-11/srfi-11.html). (If you want to use this for Guile, you will need to adjust the syntax used for optional arguments.)

This version is tailored for Scheme in a number of ways:

- The length of the list is calculated only once, at the beginning. At each split, the length of the split parts is passed to each recursive call.
- The merge step uses a right-unfold rather than a left-unfold, to be tail-recursive. This results in a reversed list at each step.
- Rather than reverse the list at each merge, I just keep a flag saying whether the lists are reversed. The merging step takes this flag into account and then does the right kind of merge to maintain sort stability.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain of the protocol here, but are you actually asking a question, or do you just want a general critique?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm looking for general critique of style, as well as ways to make the code even more performant (algorithmically speaking, not so much micro-optimisation-wise). I actually do have a more performant version of this code, which I'll post as an answer. Soon. :-)

Comment: Since you bother to call out the gotcha with `lt?`, why not fix the code like so: `(eq? (and (lt? (car r) (car l)) #t) flip)`

Comment: @MartinNeal Mostly because, if I'm going there, I may as well define an XNOR operation. Which I'm still considering doing. :-) But actually, I think I can adapt your idea to use `not` instead, so that instead of using `(and foo #t)`, I'm just using `(not foo)` (and swapping the branches, of course). Edit coming up.

Comment: I ended up creating a `truthy=?` that uses `not`. It's like XNOR with a more readable name. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Four years, 1400 views, and two dozen upvotes before a review on a site dedicated to code reviews points toward unreviewability as a prominent feature of the code. What hinders reviewability is, I think, the high level of cognitive load the code places on anyone reading it.

### Reading

1. The cognitive load begins at the top level. Merge-sort is a well documented algorithm. Like many people interested in programming, I wrote an implementation for an algorithms class. It makes a good assignment because the details are non-trivial (and discovering those details was serious work seventy years ago when the John Von-Neumann for which computing's Von-Neumann Architecture is named, did so..."how serious?" one might ask and the answer would be "Manhattan Project serious"). I imagine I'm like some other people in that I've forgotten the ins and outs of my implementation and recycled whatever synapses were storing the pseudo-code to something else. For me, merge-sort is vaguely familiar in a sort of \$\mathcal{O}(n\log n)\$ sort of way since that's the fact that's most likely to be relevant at the `sorting` level of abstraction.
2. For the purposes of this review, I'll say that the next level down is the top level of the implementation. Here the question claims a clever implementation detail: calculating the length of the list only once. I don't recall how my implementation calculated length or whether it did...I think I used vectors/arrays rather than lists [I wrote it in either Clojure or Racket]. Anyway, being clever makes the code harder to review.
3. At the next level down, the structure induces additional cognitive load. At best the mixture of `define` and `let/let*` is inconsistent style. At worst, the `let`'s just make for less readable code of the sort that made nested `define`'s worth implementing in Scheme itself.
4. Finally, there's variable names.

### Advice

1. Help the reader by commenting the code. Don't require expertise in merge-sort as a pre-requisite to understanding. Consider using something like the [HtDP Program Recipe](http://www.htdp.org/2001-01-18/Book/node14.htm) as a starting point. Explain the algorithm and use the terms of that explanation in the implementation.
2. I'm reminded of Kernighan's Lever: *Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?* Looking at the code, it isn't obvious where the innovation is implemented. Even after I obtain some level of merge-sort knowledge, I still have detective work to understand the innovation. Make the innovation explicit.
3. Make everything explicit using `define` rather than `let/let*` the syntax is better and the high level concepts can be articulated together rather than mixed in among the implementation details, e.g. `merge` can be defined alongside `truthy=?`, `mid`, etc.
4. There's no need to name parameters/variables using the criteria for minified JavaScript. `l` and `r` might be abstractions 'left' and 'right' but left and right are not abstractions that are explicit in the code. It's only via research that a reader might possibly make the connection.

A bit more on Item *2*: If performance is a concern the question of why lists and parameter passing  rather than vectors or some other data structure seems relevant. Going further, benchmarking is probably the best justification for added complexity:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Fast sorting seems to be a place where using an FFI is the road to meaningful improvement for interestingly sized data.