# Merging list tails in Scheme

Tags: scheme

In [my last post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/105874/216), I wrote a long, non-general tail-merging<sup>†</sup> facility for insertion sort. I thought I should instead write a general-purpose tail-merging function, that works even when the two lists are of different lengths. So here it is (requires [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)):

```
;;; Returns a list that has the same content as `lst`, sharing tail with `base`.
;;; Element comparisons use `eqv?`.
(define (merge-tail lst base)
  ;; `uniq1` and `uniq2` are guaranteed not to be `eqv?` to anything else.
  ;; This ensures that `breakpoint` always has a value, without any hacks.
  (define uniq1 (list 'uniq1))
  (define uniq2 (list 'uniq2))
  (define breakpoint (list-index (lambda (x y) (not (eqv? x y)))
                                 (reverse (cons uniq1 base))
                                 (reverse (cons uniq2 lst))))
  (append (drop-right lst breakpoint) (take-right base breakpoint)))
```

(In Racket, you can replace `(list 'uniq1)` with `(box 'uniq1)` (and similarly for `uniq2`), and `(lambda (x y) (not (eqv? x y)))` with `(negate eqv?)`.)

Is there a more stylish or performant way to write this code? (Note, I'm trying to not mutate either list. If the `lst` list is linear-update, then of course you can use `append!` and `drop-right!`.)

<sup>†</sup> The process of merging tails is to ensure that two lists share the longest tail possible. This is especially useful for immutable lists.

Answer (score 1):

A minor detail: In output it can be hard to tell the difference between `(cons #f #f)` and `(cons #f #f)` i.e. between `uniq1` and `uniq2`. An alternative is to write `(list 'uniq1)` in order to get a unique value.

For comparison here is a version of `merge-tail` written using named let rather than using indices. Here the common tail between `xs` and `ys` are found, and two new lists using the shared tail is returned.

```
(define (reverse-append rxs ys)
  (if (null? rxs)
      ys
      (reverse-append (cdr rxs) (cons (car rxs) ys))))

(define (merge-tail xs ys)
  (let loop ([tail '()]
             [rxs  (reverse xs)]
             [rys  (reverse ys)])
    (cond
      [(eqv? (car rxs) (car rys))
       (loop (cons (car rxs) tail)
             (cdr rxs)
             (cdr rys))]
      [else
       ;; tail is now equal to the common tail of xs and ys
       (values (reverse-append rxs tail)
               (reverse-append rys tail))])))
```

This solution will fail if `xs` and `ys` are cyclic lists with equal elements.
So in the terminology of srfi 1, the solution only works for proper lists.

Comment: Thanks, I like your `(list 'uniq1)` (or `(box 'uniq1)` in Racket) comment, which is useful for debugging. As regards your version, SRFI 1 has `append-reverse` (though if you didn't write your version to use SRFI 1, then implementing your own is understandable). Also, a fundamental difference between your version and mine is that mine uses a base list whose elements are being reused, and yours creates brand new lists for both `xs` and `ys`. Both are valid solutions; they solve different problems. :-) (And yeah, no `reverse`-based solutions work for cyclic lists.)

Comment: I had forgotten `append-reverse` was in srfi 1.